# python: yaml data from another yaml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

I have different YAML files with a various data structure (example 1).
In my project, I have to take some informations from those files.
I've wrote another YAML file to take the resources that I need (example 2).

1. Example file `res1.yaml`:

   ```
   ---
   form_title: mytitle
   icons:
     1:
       icon: dog_icon
       link: '/my/file/path1/file1'
     2:
       icon: wolf_icon
       link: '/my/file/path2/file2'
     3:
       icon: cat_icon
       link: '/my/file/path3/file3'
     4:
       icon: rabbit_icon
       link: '/my/file/path4/file4'
   ---
   ```
2. Example file `myapp_res.yaml`:

   ```
   ---
   resources:
      1:
        res: res1.yaml
        res_type: yaml
      2:
        res: res2.jpg
        res_type: image

   data:
       my_form_title:
         res: 1
         type: text
         var:
        form_title
       my_needed_icon:
         res: 1
         type: icon
         var:
        icons:
           1: link
   #etc...
   ---
   ```

I use this script to get info like "my_form_title":

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
myapp_res = yaml.load(myapp_res.yaml)
test_var = "my_form_title"
my_data = myapp_res["data"][test_var]
my_resource = my_data["res"]
my_res_file = myapp_res["resources"][my_resource]["res"]
yamel_res = yaml.load(my_res_file)
my_var = my_data["var"]
print(yamel_res[my_var])
```

But how can I get data in a sub-path like "my_needed_icon"?
with previous script I get the error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

I can only change the structure of myapp_res.yaml, and, obviously my python script.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
my_res_file = myapp_res["resources"][my_resources]["res"]
```

uses a variable `my_resources`, assuming that is assigned from `my_data['resources']`, you are indeed a dictionary that cannot be used as an index (but it is a guess, `my_resources` is not defined in your source).

You probably meant to write:

```
my_res_file = myapp_res["resources"][my_resource]["res"]
```

(note the dropped `s` from `my_resources`)

Comment: I've made a mistake when I've copied the code. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @luca if that solves the problem, then please mark the answer, then others know this solved your problem